# Move caret to the end of newly added element in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I am struggling to move the caret from its current position to the newly added DOM element within `contenteditable` element.

I want any text added within the parent `contenteditable` element, to be within `<p class="taskPara" />`.

The problem code (I suspect) is at the end.

DOM:

```
  <div className="tasksParent inline-block min-h-16">
    <div
      contentEditable
      spellCheck
      suppressContentEditableWarning
      onInput={inputHandler}
      className="inline-block w-10/12"
    />
  </div
```

Js:

```
  const inputHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff
    execCommandHandler();
  };

  const execCommandHandler = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const node = selection.anchorNode;
    const nodeParent = node.parentNode;
    if (
      (node.nodeName === "P" && node.className === "taskPara") ||
      (nodeParent.nodeName == "P" && nodeParent.className == "taskPara")
    ) {
    // do some stuff
    } else {

      // from here-on is the code to insert
      // <p class="taskPara"/> element & 
      // text as typed by user, within
 
      const nodeTxt = node.textContent;

      // capture the text added by user 
      // & delete it
      const rng = new Range();
      rng.setStart(node, 0);
      rng.setEnd(node, nodeTxt.length);
      rng.deleteContents();

      // create <p> and insert user typed text within
      const ele = document.createElement("p");
      ele.className = "taskPara";
      ele.textContent = nodeTxt;
      rng.insertNode(ele);

      // Move the caret immediately after the inserted DOM
      // note: PROBLEM CODE follows:
      const newRng = new Range();
      const firstChild = nodeParent.firstChild;
      newRng.setStart(firstChild, 0);
      newRng.setEnd(firstChild, firstChild.textContent.length > 0 ? firstChild.textContent.length : 0);
      console.log("newRng: ", newRng);
      rng.collapse(true);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(newRng);
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/contenteditable-ym56f?file=/src/App.js

I believe the code is sound except of the last section where the caret needs to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The amended execCommandHandler:

```
  const execCommandHandler = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const node = selection.anchorNode;
    const nodeParent = node.parentNode;
    if (
      (node.nodeName === "P" && node.className === "taskPara") ||
      (nodeParent.nodeName === "P" && nodeParent.className === "taskPara")
    ) {
     // some stuff
    } else {

      const nodeTxt = node.textContent;

      if (nodeTxt.length) {

        const rng = new Range();
        rng.setStart(node, 0);
        rng.setEnd(node, nodeTxt.length);
        rng.deleteContents();

        const ele = document.createElement("p");
        ele.className = "taskPara";
        ele.textContent = nodeTxt;
        rng.insertNode(ele);

        const newRng = new Range();
        const { children } = nodeParent;
        const firstChild = children[0];

        // Move the caret immediately after the inserted span
        newRng.setStart(firstChild, 0);
        newRng.setEnd(firstChild, nodeTxt.length);
        newRng.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(newRng);
      }
    }
  };
```